# spark onExecutorMetricsUpdate cannot get executor_id

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In the code below, in pyspark `2.x`, using `executorMetricsUpdate.execId()` always gave an executor id that was numeric, such as `'31'` (string type though). But after upgrading from pyspark `2.x` to `3.4.1` the `executor_id` is always `'driver'`. Why is that? I rely on this executor_id to create a report with stats about memory usage. Is there a way I can access the executor for which the metric is for?

```
def onExecutorMetricsUpdate(self, executorMetricsUpdate):
    executor_id = executorMetricsUpdate.execId()
```

UPDATE:

In my config I have:

```
"spark.master": "yarn",
```

Also, if I modify my spark job to return the machine it's being run on, I can see that multiple machines in my cluster have been used.

If I hit the Spark API endpoint

```
...stages/<stage_id>/<attempt_id>/taskList
```

I can see multiple tasks, in different hosts, but all of the memory metrics (e.g. peakExecutionMemory) are set to 0:

```
  "taskId" : 0,
  "index" : 0,
  "attempt" : 0,
  "partitionId" : 0,
  "launchTime" : "2023-11-30T13:48:28.018GMT",
  "duration" : 11850,
  "executorId" : "127",
  "host" : "xxxxxxx",
  "status" : "SUCCESS",
  "taskLocality" : "PROCESS_LOCAL",
  "speculative" : false,
  "accumulatorUpdates" : [ ],
  "taskMetrics" : {
    "executorDeserializeTime" : 750,
    "executorDeserializeCpuTime" : 666813421,
    "executorRunTime" : 10990,
    "executorCpuTime" : 129812934,
    "resultSize" : 1366,
    "jvmGcTime" : 0,
    "resultSerializationTime" : 4,
    "memoryBytesSpilled" : 0,
    "diskBytesSpilled" : 0,
    "peakExecutionMemory" : 0,
    "inputMetrics" : {
      "bytesRead" : 0,
      "recordsRead" : 0
    },
```

If I hit the `/executors` endpoint, I only see "driver"

UPDATE 2:

I ran my spark app using pyspark from a user machine (different than the spark worker machines):

```
# this utility function which sets a few conf_dict variables
def custom_create_context(..):
  conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAll(conf_dict.items())
  ss = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
  sc = ss.sparkContext
  return sc, ss

  # called by:

sc, ss = custom_create_context(conf_dict={
    "spark.app.name":                       "ftest1",
    "spark.driver.memory":                  "2g",
    "spark.executor.memory":                "2g",
    "spark.executor.cores":                 "1", 
    "spark.task.cpus":                      "1", 
    "spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors": "1000",
    "spark.master": "yarn",
}, show_report=True)

# register listener

listener = MemoryReporter(sc, report_dir)
sc._jsc.sc().addSparkListener(listener)

# submit work to spark
x = [some data]
result = sc.parallelize(x, numSlices=len(x)).map(lambda x: myfunc(x)).collect()
print(result)
```

conf_dict vars:

```
spark.app.name: xxx
spark.driver.memory: 2g
spark.executor.memory: 2g
spark.executor.cores: 1
spark.task.cpus: 1
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors: 1000
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARK_WITH_NFS: true
spark.executorEnv.SPARK_WITH_NFS: true
spark.driverEnv.SPARK_WITH_NFS: true
spark.master: yarn
spark.submit.deployMode: client
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled: true
spark.shuffle.service.enabled: true
spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout: 120s
spark.dynamicAllocation.cachedExecutorIdleTimeout: 300s
spark.driver.cores: 4
spark.driver.maxResultSize: 32g
spark.yarn.am.waitTime: 30s
spark.ui.showConsoleProgress: true
spark.worker.ui.retainedExecutors: 5000
spark.ui.retainedDeadExecutors: 5000
spark.eventLog.enabled: true
spark.eventLog.dir: hdfs:///spark-history
spark.starvation.timeout: 90s
spark.local.dir: xxx
spark.python.worker.memory: 1024m
spark.pyspark.python: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON: xxx
spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON: xx
spark.driverEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.VAULT_BUE_CACHE: xxx
spark.executorEnv.VAULT_BUE_CACHE: xxx
spark.driverEnv.VAULT_BUE_CACHE: xxx

spark.redaction.regex: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SHELL: /bin/bash
spark.executorEnv.SHELL: /bin/bash
spark.driverEnv.SHELL: /bin/bash

spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.RCFILE: xxx
spark.executorEnv.RCFILE: xxx
spark.driverEnv.RCFILE: xxx

spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION: 3.2a
spark.executorEnv.TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION: 3.2a
spark.driverEnv.TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION: 3.2a



spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.BSTINPUTS: .:/data/app/latex/bst/:/usr/share/texmf/bibtex/bst//:
spark.executorEnv.BSTINPUTS: .:/data/app/latex/bst/:/usr/share/texmf/bibtex/bst//:
spark.driverEnv.BSTINPUTS: .:/data/app/latex/bst/:/usr/share/texmf/bibtex/bst//:


spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.LOGNAME: xxx
spark.executorEnv.LOGNAME: xxx
spark.driverEnv.LOGNAME: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.XDG_SESSION_TYPE: tty
spark.executorEnv.XDG_SESSION_TYPE: tty
spark.driverEnv.XDG_SESSION_TYPE: tty
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.TEXINPUTS: .:/data/app/latex/style/:/usr/share/texmf/tex//:
spark.executorEnv.TEXINPUTS: .:/data/app/latex/style/:/usr/share/texmf/tex//:
spark.driverEnv.TEXINPUTS: .:/data/app/latex/style/:/usr/share/texmf/tex//:


spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.VIRTUAL_ENV: xxx
spark.executorEnv.VIRTUAL_ENV: xxx
spark.driverEnv.VIRTUAL_ENV: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.VAULT_TMPFS: xxx
spark.executorEnv.VAULT_TMPFS: xxx
spark.driverEnv.VAULT_TMPFS: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.BIBINPUTS: .:/data/app/latex/:/usr/share/texmf/bibtex/bib//:
spark.executorEnv.BIBINPUTS: .:/data/app/latex/:/usr/share/texmf/bibtex/bib//:
spark.driverEnv.BIBINPUTS: .:/data/app/latex/:/usr/share/texmf/bibtex/bib//:
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.ORACLE_HOME: /app/oracle
spark.executorEnv.ORACLE_HOME: /app/oracle
spark.driverEnv.ORACLE_HOME: /app/oracle

spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SSH_CONNECTION: xxx
spark.executorEnv.SSH_CONNECTION: xxx
spark.driverEnv.SSH_CONNECTION: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.HOMEBREW
spark.driverEnv.GIT_BASE: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.TERMINFO: /usr/share/terminfo
spark.executorEnv.TERMINFO: /usr/share/terminfo
spark.driverEnv.TERMINFO: /usr/share/terminfo
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.TERM: screen
spark.executorEnv.TERM: screen
spark.driverEnv.TERM: screen
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.USER: xxx
spark.executorEnv.USER: xxx
spark.driverEnv.USER: xxx

spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.LC_TERMINAL_VERSION: 3.4.20
spark.executorEnv.LC_TERMINAL_VERSION: 3.4.20
spark.driverEnv.LC_TERMINAL_VERSION: 3.4.20
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_SSL: true
spark.executorEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_SSL: true
spark.driverEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_SSL: true
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SHLVL: 2
spark.executorEnv.SHLVL: 2
spark.driverEnv.SHLVL: 2


spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.XDG_SESSION_ID: 3
spark.executorEnv.XDG_SESSION_ID: 3
spark.driverEnv.XDG_SESSION_ID: 3
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PROFILE_DEBUG: no
spark.executorEnv.PROFILE_DEBUG: no
spark.driverEnv.PROFILE_DEBUG: no
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: xxx
spark.executorEnv.XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: xx
spark.driverEnv.XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PROCPS_USERLEN: 16
spark.executorEnv.PROCPS_USERLEN: 16
spark.driverEnv.PROCPS_USERLEN: 16
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SSH_CLIENT: xxx
spark.executorEnv.SSH_CLIENT: xxx
spark.driverEnv.SSH_CLIENT: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: xx
spark.executorEnv.REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: xxx
spark.driverEnv.REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: xxx

spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.DOCKER_HOST: unix:///xx
spark.executorEnv.DOCKER_HOST: unix:///xxx
spark.driverEnv.DOCKER_HOST: unix:///xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.TNS_ADMIN: xxx
spark.executorEnv.TNS_ADMIN: xxx
spark.driverEnv.TNS_ADMIN: xxx

spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.XDG_DATA_DIRS: /usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
spark.executorEnv.XDG_DATA_DIRS: /usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
spark.driverEnv.XDG_DATA_DIRS: /usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PATH: xxx
spark.executorEnv.PATH: xxx
spark.driverEnv.PATH: xxx

spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: unix:path=/xxx
spark.executorEnv.DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: unix:path=/xxx
spark.driverEnv.DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: unix:path=/xxx

spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SSH_TTY: /dev/pts/0
spark.executorEnv.SSH_TTY: /dev/pts/0
spark.driverEnv.SSH_TTY: /dev/pts/0
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.OLDPWD: /xx
spark.executorEnv.OLDPWD: x
spark.driverEnv.OLDPWD: xx

spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR: xxx
spark.executorEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR: xxx
spark.driverEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR: xxx

spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SSL_CERT_FILE: xxx
spark.executorEnv.SSL_CERT_FILE: xxx
spark.driverEnv.SSL_CERT_FILE: xx

spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.CONSUL_TOKEN_JSON: xxx
spark.executorEnv.CONSUL_TOKEN_JSON: xxx
spark.driverEnv.CONSUL_TOKEN_JSON: xx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.LOGNAME: x
spark.executorEnv.LOGNAME: x
spark.driverEnv.LOGNAME: x
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.XDG_SESSION_TYPE: tty
spark.executorEnv.XDG_SESSION_TYPE: tty
spark.driverEnv.XDG_SESSION_TYPE: tty
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.TEXINPUTS: .:/data/app/latex/style/:/usr/share/texmf/tex//:
spark.executorEnv.TEXINPUTS: .:/data/app/latex/style/:/usr/share/texmf/tex//:
spark.driverEnv.TEXINPUTS: .:/data/app/latex/style/:/usr/share/texmf/tex//:
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.CONSUL_LEASE_FILE: xxx
spark.executorEnv.CONSUL_LEASE_FILE: xxx
spark.driverEnv.CONSUL_LEASE_FILE: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN_ACCESSOR: xxx
spark.executorEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN_ACCESSOR: xxx
spark.driverEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN_ACCESSOR: xxx

spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN: xxx
spark.executorEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN: xxx
spark.driverEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN: xxx

spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.VIRTUAL_ENV: xxx
spark.executorEnv.VIRTUAL_ENV: xxx
spark.driverEnv.VIRTUAL_ENV: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.VAULT_TMPFS: xxx
spark.executorEnv.VAULT_TMPFS: xxx
spark.driverEnv.VAULT_TMPFS: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.BIBINPUTS: .:/data/app/latex/:/usr/share/texmf/bibtex/bib//:
spark.executorEnv.BIBINPUTS: .:/data/app/latex/:/usr/share/texmf/bibtex/bib//:
spark.driverEnv.BIBINPUTS: .:/data/app/latex/:/usr/share/texmf/bibtex/bib//:
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.ORACLE_HOME: /app/oracle
spark.executorEnv.ORACLE_HOME: /app/oracle
spark.driverEnv.ORACLE_HOME: /app/oracle

spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SSH_CONNECTION: xxx
spark.executorEnv.SSH_CONNECTION: xxx
spark.driverEnv.SSH_CONNECTION: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE: 1
spark.executorEnv.HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE: 1
spark.driverEnv.HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE: 1
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN_FILE: xxx
spark.executorEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN_FILE: xxx
spark.driverEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN_FILE: xxx

spark.executorEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN_FILE: xxx                                                                                                                             
spark.driverEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN_FILE: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.XDG_SESSION_CLASS: user
spark.executorEnv.XDG_SESSION_CLASS: user
spark.driverEnv.XDG_SESSION_CLASS: user
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.GIT_BASE: xxx
spark.executorEnv.GIT_BASE: xxx
spark.driverEnv.GIT_BASE: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.TERMINFO: /usr/share/terminfo
spark.executorEnv.TERMINFO: /usr/share/terminfo
spark.driverEnv.TERMINFO: /usr/share/terminfo
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.TERM: screen
spark.executorEnv.TERM: screen
spark.driverEnv.TERM: screen
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.USER: xxx
spark.executorEnv.USER: xxx
spark.driverEnv.USER: xxx

spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_SSL: true
spark.executorEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_SSL: true
spark.driverEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_SSL: true
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SHLVL: 2
spark.executorEnv.SHLVL: 2
spark.driverEnv.SHLVL: 2


spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.GIT_EXAMPLE: xxx
spark.executorEnv.GIT_EXAMPLE: xxx
spark.driverEnv.GIT_EXAMPLE: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.XDG_SESSION_ID: 3
spark.executorEnv.XDG_SESSION_ID: 3
spark.driverEnv.XDG_SESSION_ID: 3
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PROFILE_DEBUG: no
spark.executorEnv.PROFILE_DEBUG: no
spark.driverEnv.PROFILE_DEBUG: no
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: xxx
spark.executorEnv.XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: xxx
spark.driverEnv.XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PROCPS_USERLEN: 16
spark.executorEnv.PROCPS_USERLEN: 16
spark.driverEnv.PROCPS_USERLEN: 16
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYTHONBREAKPOINT: pudb.set_trace
spark.executorEnv.PYTHONBREAKPOINT: pudb.set_trace
spark.driverEnv.PYTHONBREAKPOINT: pudb.set_trace
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SSH_CLIENT: xxx
spark.executorEnv.SSH_CLIENT: xx
spark.driverEnv.SSH_CLIENT: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
spark.executorEnv.REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
spark.driverEnv.REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.DOCKER_HOST: unix:///xxx
spark.executorEnv.DOCKER_HOST: unix:///xxx
spark.driverEnv.DOCKER_HOST: unix:///xx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.TNS_ADMIN: xxx
spark.executorEnv.TNS_ADMIN: xxx
spark.driverEnv.TNS_ADMIN: xxx

spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.XDG_DATA_DIRS: /usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
spark.executorEnv.XDG_DATA_DIRS: /usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
spark.driverEnv.XDG_DATA_DIRS: /usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PATH: xxx
spark.executorEnv.PATH: xxx
spark.driverEnv.PATH: xxx

spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: unix:path=xxx
spark.executorEnv.DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: unix:path=xx
spark.driverEnv.DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: unix:path=xxx


spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SSH_TTY: /dev/pts/0
spark.executorEnv.SSH_TTY: /dev/pts/0
spark.driverEnv.SSH_TTY: /dev/pts/0
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.OLDPWD: xxx
spark.executorEnv.OLDPWD: xxx
spark.driverEnv.OLDPWD: xxx


spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR: xxx
spark.executorEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR: xx
spark.driverEnv.CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR: xxx


spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SSL_CERT_FILE: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
spark.executorEnv.SSL_CERT_FILE: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
spark.driverEnv.SSL_CERT_FILE: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.CURL_CA_BUNDLE: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
spark.executorEnv.CURL_CA_BUNDLE: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
spark.driverEnv.CURL_CA_BUNDLE: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt



spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_RDD_CODE_SERIALIZER: pyspark.serializers.CloudPickleSerializer
spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_RDD_CODE_SERIALIZER: pyspark.serializers.CloudPickleSerializer
spark.driverEnv.PYSPARK_RDD_CODE_SERIALIZER: pyspark.serializers.CloudPickleSerializer
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_RDD_DATA_SERIALIZER: pyspark.serializers.CloudPickleSerializer
spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_RDD_DATA_SERIALIZER: pyspark.serializers.CloudPickleSerializer
spark.driverEnv.PYSPARK_RDD_DATA_SERIALIZER: pyspark.serializers.CloudPickleSerializer
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.HADOOP_HOME: /.../hadoop/current
spark.executorEnv.HADOOP_HOME: xxx
spark.driverEnv.HADOOP_HOME: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.HADOOP_COMMON_HOME: xxx
spark.executorEnv.HADOOP_COMMON_HOME: xxx
spark.driverEnv.HADOOP_COMMON_HOME: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.HADOOP_HDFS_HOME: xxx
spark.executorEnv.HADOOP_HDFS_HOME: xxx
spark.driverEnv.HADOOP_HDFS_HOME: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.HADOOP_YARN_HOME: xxx
spark.executorEnv.HADOOP_YARN_HOME: xxx
spark.driverEnv.HADOOP_YARN_HOME: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME: xxx
spark.executorEnv.HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME: xxx
spark.driverEnv.HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.HADOOP_CONF_DIR: xxx
spark.executorEnv.HADOOP_CONF_DIR: xxx
spark.driverEnv.HADOOP_CONF_DIR: xxx
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.OMP_NUM_THREADS: 1
spark.executorEnv.OMP_NUM_THREADS: 1
spark.driverEnv.OMP_NUM_THREADS: 1
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.SPARK_HOME: xxx
spark.executorEnv.SPARK_HOME: xxx
spark.driverEnv.SPARK_HOME: xxx
```

Update 3:

The MemoryReporter is a custom class that receives the events described here https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.3/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener:

```
API_URL_VAR = "spark.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter.param.PROXY_URI_BASES"

pyspark_v3 = pyspark.__version__.startswith("3.")


class SparkListener(object):
    """
    https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.3/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener
    """

    def onApplicationEnd(self, applicationEnd):
        pass

    def onApplicationStart(self, applicationStart):
        pass

    def onBlockManagerAdded(self, blockManagerAdded):
        pass

    def onBlockManagerRemoved(self, blockManagerRemoved):
        pass

    def onBlockUpdated(self, blockUpdated):
        pass

    def onEnvironmentUpdate(self, environmentUpdate):
        pass

    def onExecutorAdded(self, executorAdded):
        pass

    def onExecutorBlacklisted(self, executorBlacklisted):
        pass

    def onExecutorMetricsUpdate(self, executorMetricsUpdate):
        pass

    def onExecutorRemoved(self, executorRemoved):
        pass

    def onExecutorUnblacklisted(self, executorUnblacklisted):
        pass

    def onJobEnd(self, jobEnd):
        pass

    def onJobStart(self, jobStart):
        pass

    def onNodeBlacklisted(self, nodeBlacklisted):
        pass

    def onNodeUnblacklisted(self, nodeUnblacklisted):
        pass

    def onOtherEvent(self, event):
        pass

    def onSpeculativeTaskSubmitted(self, speculativeTask):
        pass

    def onStageCompleted(self, stageCompleted):
        pass

    def onStageSubmitted(self, stageSubmitted):
        pass

    def onTaskEnd(self, taskEnd):
        pass

    def onTaskGettingResult(self, taskGettingResult):
        pass

    def onTaskStart(self, taskStart):
        pass

    def onUnpersistRDD(self, unpersistRDD):
        pass

    class Java:
        implements = ["org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerInterface"]


def _scala_iterable_to_py_list(scala_iterable):
    if isinstance(scala_iterable, Iterable):
        return list(scala_iterable)

    py_list = []
    it = scala_iterable.toIterator()
    while it.hasNext():
        py_list.append(it.next())
    return py_list


def _scala_set_to_py_set(scala_set):
    return set(_scala_iterable_to_py_list(scala_set))


class MemoryReporter(SparkListener):
    def __init__(self, sc, report_dir):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)

        self._sc = sc
        self._report_dir = os.environ.get(SPARK_MEMORY_REPORT_DIR_ENVIRON, report_dir)

        self._spark_conf = sc.getConf()

        self._username = self._sc._jvm.java.lang.System.getProperty("user.name")
        self._application_id = self._spark_conf.get("spark.app.id", None)

        spark_executor_memory = self._spark_conf.get("spark.executor.memory", None)
        self._requested_limit_byte = self._parse_memory_from_conf(spark_executor_memory)
        self._actual_limit_byte = 0  # will be updated once job is running

        self._executor_task = {}  # type: Dict[int, int]
        self._task_memory = {}  # type: Dict[int, int]
        self._stage_tasks = {}  # type: Dict[int, Set[int]]
        self._stage_last_attempt_id = {}
        self._active_jobs = 0

    def _parse_memory_from_conf(self, memory):
        pass # edited out for briefness

    def _reset_memory_stats(self):
        pass # edited out for briefness

    def _format_memory_usage(self, x):
        pass # edited out for briefness

    def _print_report(self, task_memory):
        pass # edited out for briefness

    def update_stage_info_v2(self):
        status_store = self._sc._jsc.sc().statusStore()

        all_jobs = _scala_iterable_to_py_list(status_store.jobsList(None))
        all_stage_ids = []
        for job in all_jobs:
            all_stage_ids += _scala_iterable_to_py_list(job.stageIds())

        for stage_id in all_stage_ids:
            if stage_id in self._stage_tasks:
                continue

            stage_data = _scala_iterable_to_py_list(status_store.stageData(stage_id, True))
            if not stage_data:
                continue

            last_stage_data = stage_data[-1]
            stage_status = last_stage_data.status().toString()
            if stage_status != "ACTIVE" and stage_status != "PENDING" and last_stage_data.tasks().isDefined():
                stage_tasks = stage_data[-1].tasks().get()
                stage_task_ids = _scala_set_to_py_set(stage_tasks.keys())
                self._stage_tasks[stage_id] = stage_task_ids

    def update_stage_info_v3(self):
        """
        In pyspark 3 we don't have:
        - stage_info.status
        - status_store.stageData(stage_id, True)
        - a way to get task info from the stage (only via REST API)
        """
        status_store = self._sc._jsc.sc().statusStore()
        all_jobs = _scala_iterable_to_py_list(status_store.jobsList(None))
        all_stage_ids = []
        for job in all_jobs:
            all_stage_ids += _scala_iterable_to_py_list(job.stageIds())

        for stage_id in all_stage_ids:
            if stage_id in self._stage_tasks:
                continue

            app_id = self._sc.applicationId
            proxy_host = self._sc.getConf().get(API_URL_VAR)
            if not proxy_host:
                continue

            stages_api_url = f"{proxy_host}/api/v1/applications/{app_id}/stages/{stage_id}"

            try:
                response = requests.get(stages_api_url)
                stages_data = response.json()
            except Exception as ex:
                self.logger.warning(f"Failed getting stages_data from API Url: {stages_api_url} ex: {ex}")
                continue

            last_stage_attempt = stages_data[-1]
            last_stage_status = last_stage_attempt.get("status")
            if last_stage_status and last_stage_status != "ACTIVE" and last_stage_status != "PENDING":
                attempt_id = last_stage_attempt.get("attemptId")
                self._stage_last_attempt_id[stage_id] = attempt_id
                if attempt_id is not None:  # careful as it can be 0 (evaluates to False)
                    tasks_info_api_url = (
                        f"{proxy_host}/api/v1/applications/{app_id}/stages/{stage_id}/{attempt_id}/taskList"
                    )
                    try:
                        response2 = requests.get(tasks_info_api_url)
                        tasks_info_data = response2.json()
                        self.logger.debug(f"tasks_info_api_url: {tasks_info_api_url}")
                        task_ids = [t["taskId"] for t in tasks_info_data]
                        self._stage_tasks[stage_id] = task_ids

                    except Exception as ex:
                        self.logger.warning(f"Failed getting tasks_info_data API url: {tasks_info_api_url} ex: {ex}")
                        continue

    def _update_stage_tasks(self):
        if pyspark_v3:
            self.update_stage_info_v3()
        else:
            self.update_stage_info_v2()

    def _save_csv(self, job_id, df):
        pass # edited out for briefness

    def _save_report(self, job_id, task_memory):
        pass # edited out for briefness

    def onTaskStart(self, taskStart):
        task_id = taskStart.taskInfo().taskId()
        executor_id = taskStart.taskInfo().executorId()

        self.logger.debug("setting executor '{}' to task '{}'".format(executor_id, task_id))
        self._executor_task[executor_id] = task_id

    def onExecutorMetricsUpdate(self, executorMetricsUpdate):
        executor_id = executorMetricsUpdate.execId()  # returns 'driver' in pyspark > 3 but a number in pyspark < 2
        if pyspark_v3:
            # https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/monitoring.html
            # https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.1.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/metrics/ExecutorMetricType.scala#L196
            memory_byte = 0
            metrics = executorMetricsUpdate.executorUpdates().values().toList()  # Scala view to values
            metrics = [metrics.apply(i) for i in range(metrics.size())]
            for m in metrics:
                memory_byte = max(memory_byte, m.getMetricValue("JVMHeapMemory"))
        else:
            # Backward compatible. e.g. v2.3.4
            memory_byte = executorMetricsUpdate.cgroupMetrics().memoryUsageInBytes()
            self._actual_limit_byte = max(
                self._actual_limit_byte, executorMetricsUpdate.cgroupMetrics().memoryLimitInBytes()
            )

        task_id = self._executor_task.get(executor_id, None)
        if task_id is None:
            # would still receive metrics updates after job finishes
            self.logger.debug("Cannot find corresponding task for executor {}".format(executor_id))
            return

        self._task_memory[task_id] = max(self._task_memory.get(task_id, 0), memory_byte)

    def getExecutorMetricsFromAPI(self):
        """
        Get Spark metrics from the Spark API
        Potentially switch this to use this end point:
        application_1697883854732_43137/api/v1/applications/application_1697883854732_43137/executors
        Or another option is to record this info in update_stage_info_v3() directly
        """
        self.logger.info("Getting metrics from Spark API")
        app_id = self._sc.applicationId
        proxy_host = self._sc.getConf().get(API_URL_VAR)
        if not proxy_host:
            return

        for stage_id, attempt_id in self._stage_last_attempt_id.items():
            tasks_info_api_url = f"{proxy_host}/api/v1/applications/{app_id}/stages/{stage_id}/{attempt_id}/taskList"
            try:
                resp = requests.get(tasks_info_api_url)
                tasks_info_data = resp.json()
                for task_info in tasks_info_data:
                    task_id = task_info.get("taskId")
                    if task_id is not None:  # warning, this can be 0 (evaluates to False)
                        peak_mem = task_info["taskMetrics"]["peakExecutionMemory"]
                        task_max_mem = max(self._task_memory.get(task_id, 0), peak_mem)
                        self._task_memory[task_info["taskId"]] = task_max_mem
                        self.logger.debug(
                            f"metrics_from_api: stage: {stage_id} task: {task_id} task_max_mem: {task_max_mem}"
                        )

            except Exception as ex:
                # Even if one fails, we try the others to get some data for the report
                self.logger.warning(f"metrics_from_api: failed getting tasks_info url: {tasks_info_api_url} ex: {ex}")

    def onJobStart(self, jobStart):
        self._active_jobs += 1

    def onJobEnd(self, jobEnd):
        self._active_jobs -= 1
        job_id = jobEnd.jobId()

        if self._active_jobs == 0:
            self._update_stage_tasks()
            self.logger.info(f"stage_task updated: {self._stage_tasks} job: {job_id}")

            if self._task_memory:

                self.logger.debug(f"Collected task memory: {self._task_memory} for job_id: {job_id}")

                self._print_report(self._task_memory)

                self._save_report(job_id, self._task_memory)

                self.logger.info("More details at {}".format(get_am_ui_url(self._sc, self._spark_conf)))
            else:
                if pyspark_v3:
                    # onExecutorMetricsUpdate() isn't working as expected in pyspark 3+, so we use the RESTP API
                    self.logger.info(f"Attempting report via Spark API. version: {pyspark.__version__}")
                    self.getExecutorMetricsFromAPI()
                    self._print_report(self._task_memory)
                    self._save_report(job_id, self._task_memory)
                    self.logger.info("More details at {}".format(get_am_ui_url(self._sc, self._spark_conf)))
                else:
                    self.logger.info(f"Not enough data collected for the report of job: {job_id}")

            self._reset_memory_stats()

    def onApplicationEnd(self, applicationEnd):
        self.logger.info(
            "Spark application has ended. Access from the history server {}".format(
                get_history_server_url(self._sc, self._spark_conf)
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that one of the custom metrics we added was not made serializable as we had done for the previous spark version. That resulted in failures when sending heartbeats from the workers. Unfortunately the only hint of this problem appeared when running jobs that took more than 120 seconds (heartbeat timeout).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that probably not only your version changed, but also your cluster setup.

It is possible for an `executor_id` to be equal to `driver`. The [`SparkContext.DRIVER_IDENTIFIER`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6b1ff22dde1ead51cbf370be6e48a802daae58b6/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2824) variable in each SparkContext is equal to `driver` on 3.4.1. and each node uses this to determine whether the running process is an executor or a driver in [`BlockManagerId`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/6b1ff22dde1ead51cbf370be6e48a802daae58b6/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/BlockManagerId.scala#L67-L69):

```scala
def isDriver: Boolean = {
  executorId == SparkContext.DRIVER_IDENTIFIER
}
```

With the information that you gave us in your question it's hard to say 100% for sure (for example we don't know how you define `executorMetricsUpdate` in your code) but if your `executor_id` variable is always equal to `driver` it's possible that you're running your cluster using `--master local` instead of using an actual cluster.

If you run spark applications with `--master local` or any variant of `local` to run your code on a single machine with a single JVM process running, your driver will perform as **both** the driver and the executor.

So try to make sure you're running on an actual cluster and then you might get your wanted behaviour!

Comment: thanks! updating the question now, I am using Yarn and I have just verified that multiple nodes are in use

Comment: Could you also specify how you run your application? Is it in a spark-shell on some machine? Using spark-submit? ...? And can you add the code on how `executorMetricsUpdate` is defined in your initial code block?

Comment: Sure! I use pyspark to lunch the job via getOrCreate() from a user machine (not same as cluster machines). I just added the code I use and the config variables

Comment: Sorry I just realized I forgot to add the code on how we register the listener. I have added it now.

Comment: No worries, thanks for adding more information! Sorry for asking more (but I'm not able to go deeper without this info) but where does your `MemoryReporter` class come from? Also, can you add how you use `onExecutorMetricsUpdate` and definitely where its argument, `executorMetricsUpdate`, gets defined?

Comment: Thanks for continuing to look at it! I have just added the MemoryReporter class (custom class) that listens to the onExecutorMetricsUpdate events explained in this doc https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.3/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener. Let me know if that is not what you were asking for.

Comment: I just solved the issue! will add an answer about it

Comment: Ahhh great! Sorry for not having had a look these last days, had some busy times. Happy you found out your problem and thanks for sharing!